# Bind the function to event Angular JS Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a to do list using Angular JS. Add item button works fine and calls add function, but delete is not binding to delete function. 
Please tell me a way out.

HTML
[image: HTML]

JS
[image: JS]

Comment: I don't see anything in your HTML that's utilizing your delete function. Also, codepen/jsfiddle/github gists make it a lot easier to help, rather than screenshots.

Comment: i am dynamically adding a delete button from js for every item added which has attribute ng-click = "delete()". Also, i dont know how to use codepen/jsfiddle gists

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Try triggering the digest cycle with $scope.$apply $scope.$digest?

Comment: @IshanGupta If you're dynamically adding HTML elements, I don't think Angular isn't hooked into those elements' directives (eg, `ng-click`). I've seen this be resolved via something like `$compile`

Comment: Use the `ng-if` directive to add to the DOM tree. It will properly use the `$compile` service so that core `ng-` directives work.